# Simple integration for absolute energy formulation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

In a derivation for absolute energy equation for a structure subjected to an earthquake, the following equation appears:

$\int m \frac{d\dot v}{dt}dv =\frac{m(\dot v)^2}{2}$

Would someone please elaborate on the intermediate steps? I dont understand how we can go from the left hand side to the right hand side of this equation. We have $m$ is constant  and $v$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: What is the derivative $\frac{d(\dot v)^2}{dt}$?  Or can you integrate by parts?

Comment: It is $\frac{d}{dt} (\frac{dv}{dt})^2$

Comment: It's $2\dot v \frac{d\dot v}{dt}$.

Comment: but the original integral is with respect to $v$...

Comment: $dv \to \dot v\,dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v=v(t)$.  Then $dv=\dot v\,dt$ and we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int m\frac{d\dot v}{dt}dv&=m\int \frac{d\dot v}{dt}\dot v\,dt\\\\
&=\frac12 m\int \frac{d(\dot v)^2}{dt}\,dt\\\\
&=\frac{m(\dot v)^2}{2}
\end{align}$$